# Microsoft-Cognitive Translator hub to ignore certain words

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

Microsoft asked me to post my question here :

In microsoft translator Hub I saw that  it is possible to customize the translation and "train" the system but the system says that I need a file with 2000 words in it.

The thing is I have a web application and I don't want the translator to translate certain words like brand names;

For example the Brand "North" is translated " Norte " in Spanish which make the translation not understable.

So I don't have 2000 words to train just a list of Brand names to be ignored.

Is it possible to do this? thank you

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. You can build a custom system using a dictionary only.

See our Knowledge Base article in the Cognitive Services User Voice:
https://cognitive.uservoice.com/knowledgebase/articles/1166938-hub-building-a-custom-system-using-a-dictionary-o